# Find the Method of moments estimate

Tags: estimation, point-estimation, method-of-moments

[image]

So here i am getting E(X)=1/2,E(X^2)=0 and E(X^3)=Theta squared/4
How do i proceed now?How do i use the given x values ?

Comment: How do you obtain $E[X^2]=0$?  That implies the variable must be constantly zero, which obviously is not the case.  (The first expectation is incorrect, too.)  You can sidestep some of these issues by considering how many moments you actually need to estimate this *single* parameter $\theta$.

Comment: i took integration of x^2f(x) from -theta to theta and got 0

Comment: Yes: that's what you wrote.  But it's obviously wrong.

Comment: So how should i have approached that?

Comment: i mean i can't do this like discrete distribution right ,its given it's a pdf.

Comment: You made an elementary mistake in your integration of $x^2$, it's not a question of how you should have approached it.  As a hint: what is $- (-1)^3$?  Furthermore, pay lots of attention to @whuber's last sentence in his first comment.

Comment: Using integration is okay but you should perform the integration correctly. Note that $x^2 f(x)$ is *necessarily* non-negative everywhere, so its integral cannot be 0 anywhere. You may be less likely to make an error if you use symmetry considerations to do the integral from 0 up to $\theta$. As with jbowman I urge you to consider how many moments you need. The fact that you calculated so many suggests that perhaps you don't know what the method of moments entails. If that's the case you should ask about that (but search first!).

Comment: oh.i actually need the 1st moment right!

Comment: But what do i do after that

Comment: so euating the first moment i.e1/2 to the mean of the observed values here,i am getting the estimate to be an irrational number.But the answer given is 3

Comment: seEms like x3 and x4 shouldnt be taken into consideration while getting the moment.But why would be that?

Comment: What is the mean of $x$ when $\theta = 1$?  And when $\theta = 2$?

Comment: (3+√5+√2)/8 and (3+√5+√2)/4

Comment: The true mean of $x$, not the sample mean.

Comment: I suspect you may confused about what a probability distribution is and what a sample is.  Either I meant the true mean of $x$, in which case the numbers in your formula are irrelevant as they are the sample (which is clearly stated in the problem statement), or I meant the sample mean, in which case $\theta$ has nothing to do with the calculation, and I have no idea why you are dividing by $8$ and $4$.  (I actually meant the true mean.)    At this point, I think you might want to go to an instructor and have this cleared up... there seem to be several issues here at once.

Comment: yeah i am sorry.i was really confused.I had been trying to work that out for a long time.Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The first moment ($\mathbb{E}(X) =0$) by symmetry considerations. The second moment ($\mathbb{E}(X^2) = \frac{\theta^2}{3}$). Now equate this to the second sample moment ($\sum_{i=1}^4 x_i^2 /4 = \frac{2^2+1^2+\sqrt{5}^2+\sqrt{2}^2}{4} = 12/4=3$. So $\frac{\theta^2}{3}=3$ or $\theta = \pm3$ and we could then choose Answer (C).